# How to delete from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Ok guys from my code, I could update the edited record by pressing submit button and use this

```
$action =(isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['submit'] : null);
if($action!=null) {                 
    $id =(isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : null);

    $query="update club set adminApprove='Y' where id=$id";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    echo "<br><p style='text-align:center;color:blue'>Club record has been updated</p>";

    echo mysql_error();
```

So how can I create something like this to delete from database? Thank You

Comment: You need to write delete query to delete something from the database.

Comment: `.php?id=0+or+id<>0` - use a parametrized query

Comment: Did you even bother Googling "delete mysql php"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM club WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<br><p style='text-align:center;color:blue'>Club record has been DELETED!</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column = some_value
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_delete.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id=$id";
$result=mysql_query($query);
```